# MongoError when trying to aggregate with collection relationship

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean, meanjs

I am new to mongodb, using Mean stack from meanjs.org.

I have a model with a user collection relationship:

```
var MealSchema = new Schema({
  mealDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
mongoose.model('Meal', MealSchema);
```

I had find an implementation that works:

```
var user = req.user;
Meal.find({
  mealDate: {
    $gte: minus8days.toDate(),
    $lt: tomorrow.toDate()
  },
  user : user
  }).exec(function (err, meals) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
  } else {
    res.json(meals);
  }
});
```

But I need some grouping and aggregation so I am trying to change this code to use aggregate instead of a find, I've tried many combinations and I keep getting an error, basically the following implementation throws an error MongoError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
Meal.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        mealDate: {
          $gte: minus8days.toDate(),
          $lt: tomorrow.toDate()
        }
      }, { user: user }
    ]
  }
}]...
```

Why user:user works with find and not with aggregate? 
How can the aggregate approach be fixed?

Comment: Please try `{
  $match: {
        mealDate: {
          $gte: minus8days.toDate(),
          $lt: tomorrow.toDate()
        },
       user: user 
  }
}` and also add `function(err)` in the end of `aggregation`, it could give you more information about error?

Comment: Is the value of `user` correct `ObjectId`?

Comment: The suggestion that you gave, basically, removing the $and and array brackets doesn't work, it gives the same erorr  (Maximum call stack exceeded). Value of user is correct as I mentioned it's used in find exactly like this and it works. Function error as suggested is already there I just omitted because it doesn't add much to the question. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Meal.aggregate([
    { 
       $match: { 
           mealDate: { $gte: minus8days.toDate(), $lt: tomorrow.toDate()},
           user: user._id
       }
    }
], function(err, docs){
    if(err) console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
    if(docs) console.log("Got the docs successfully : " + JSON.stringify(docs));
});
```

Comment: Hi, this works but I got confused now. What's the reason that user:user works for find but doesn't work for aggregate? Any ideas? Thanks